# Error while loading artifacts from Artifactory to s3

Tags: artifactory

After switching from Artifactory OSS to Artifactory PRO, I tried to connect s3, but when loading artifacts, an error appears

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: S3 binary provider is supported only with HA license addon.filestore.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.permittedByLicense"
```

I use binary file. Where am i going wrong?

```
    <config version="2">
        <chain template="s3"/>
        <provider id="s3" type="s3">
           <endpoint>https://s3.amazonaws.com</endpoint>
           <identity>***</identity>
           <credential>****</credential>
           <path>filestore</path>
           <region>eu-central-1</region>
           <bucketName>bucket-name</bucketName>
        </provider>
    </config>
```

Comment: The error message generally indicates an issue with the license compatibility. However, as you mentioned 'Pro' should ideally connect to the s3.amazonaws.com endpoint. Hence, I doubt there is an issue with the steps followed to migrate from OSS to Pro. Did you follow the steps mentioned in this KB? https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-upgrade-artifactory-from-open-source-solutions-oss-to-pro/
Are you sure your instance is running as Pro?

Comment: I use docker. I replaced the oss image with the pro version.

Comment: Under the Administration tab can you see the 'Licenses'? if not, the migration from OSS -> Pro was not successful. The best solution is to spin up a new Artifactory with S3 connected -> perform an export on the OSS Artifactory -> Perform an import on Pro Artifactory

Comment: Yes, I can see "Licenses" under Administration tab.
I have trial "Enterprise" version - and everything works like a charm, however on the paid "Pro" - it doesn't. I recieve the error as stated above.
I have also found out that PRO doesn't support S3:
Here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Pro+Features - states that only "Enterprise" has S3 Object Storage.
However this article - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/S3+Object+Storage - describes S3 support in PRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself. Prior to version 6.15, S3 was only available in enterprise. After 6.15 S3 is also available in pro license